# Difficulties using InlineData in Unit Test - parameter is a controller

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I am new to testing and am now learning to use xUnit.

I have written the below test which works and gives the results I am looking for, but I think that I should be able to make it cleaner, like when using TestCase in nUnit. Therefore I am trying to use InlineData, which I understand is xUnits "TestCase", but I don't know how to do it.

When trying to set it up, as shown below (please see the outcommented lines), then it tells me

```
    [Theory]
    // [InlineData("")] // wanna use InlineData just to make the code/test cleaner.
    // [InlineData(null)]
    public async Task Get_Return_Something(
        MyController sut)
    {
        var result1 = await sut.Get(""); // when placing "sut" as param, I get: cannot convert from MyController to string. 
        var result2 = await sut.Get(null); // same applies here..

        result1.ShouldBeOfType(typeof(OkObjectResult));
        result2.ShouldBeOfType(typeof(BadRequestObjectResult));
    }
```

My question is - how do I implement the InlineData so that the test is cleaner. And is it even possible when I have a controller as a parameter?

Just to clarify it -> should there be a way to use the syntax from nUnit:

```
// something like this
[TestCase("", OkObjectResult)]
[TestCase(null, BadRequestObjectResult)]
public async Task Get_Return_Something(MyController sut, param1, param2)
{
    var result = await.sut.Get(param1);
    result.ShouldBeOfType(typeof(param2));
}
```

Maybe the nUnit example is incorrect - but I'm trying to point out, what I am looking for, by saying cleaner code. By following the TestCase-logic, I can easily expand my test to 10-15 different TestCases. And I've heard that xUnit does something similar with InlineData (which LasseVågsætherKarlsen told me wasn't possible) - or then MemberClass or ClassData.

Comment: You can't use InlineData for that, or you need to specify something like a string that the test method can then be used to construct the controller. An attribute cannot have references to objects as parameters, other than built-in literal types such as strings.

Comment: You should look at MemberData or ClassData instead.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Thank you. I can see that when trying to use ClassData, then I have to change the class into a IEnumerable (if I have understood it right) - shouldn't I be able to run/write the tests without having to touch the classes outside the testclass?

Comment: You can add MemberData, means you add a property or method to your test class that provides the test data, this is allowed to construct instances of whatever and return it.

Comment: You can approach it from different angle. Instantiate controller in the test method, but extract testing logic into dedicated method. Then in test pass controller to that method `Assert_That_Return_Something(controller)`. With such approach you will have descriptive names for test methods, important part which describes test cases will be in the test method (no need to scroll or jump around)

Comment: @Fabio there isn't really any other testlogic than the "await sut.Get(param) and the assertion - do you want me to pull that out of the testmethod? I am trying to keep the test as it is, but instead of having the act and assertion for both parameters (result1, result2), I would like to write only result.. but having the parameters both be visual like the nUnit testcase => [TestCase("")] and [TestCase(null)], but using syntax from xUnit

Comment: My point were that you keep differences (which is `sut` initialization) in the separated test methods but extract test execution and assertion into the method. With such approach tests would be easier to follow and maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I managed to get it fixed. It IS actually possible to use InlineData - just not as easy (imo) as with nUnit. Here is the solution:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("", typeof(OkObjectResult))]
[InlineData(null, typeof(BadRequestObjectResult))]
public async Task Get_Return_Something(param1, param2){

    // moq MyController with its parameters/objects
    ...


    var result = await sut.Get(param1);

    result.ShouldBeOfType(param2);
}
```

In my opinion a very easy way to do it - compared to the ones found when searching the net - hope it is useful for other too.

Answer (score 0):

### Possibility 1

1. Create a `MyControllerClassData`

```
    public class MyControllerClassData : IEnumerable<object[]>
    {
        public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator()
        {
            yield return new object[] {
                new MyController
                {
                  Id = 1,
                  // ...
                }
            };
        }
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
    }
```

2. Modify your Theory

```
    [Theory]
    [ClassData(typeof(MyControllerClassData))]
    public async Task Get_Return_Something(MyController sut)
    {
        var result1 = await sut.Get(""); // when placing "sut" as param, I get: cannot convert from MyController to string. 
        var result2 = await sut.Get(null); // same applies here..

        result1.ShouldBeOfType(typeof(OkObjectResult));
        result2.ShouldBeOfType(typeof(BadRequestObjectResult));
    }
```

### Possibility 2

1. Create the MyController class in the constructor and store it on a private property
2. Change the parameters to string and the `objectResult` that you want
3. Use always the same MyController, use the string to do the `Get()` and validate it against the `objectResult` expected.

This solution seems a lit bit cleaner, as you have one test for each situation.

Comment: I haven't been clear enough in my question, because the first possibility isn't more simple than the one I already have. What I wish to do is implement the [Testcase(param 1)]-syntax from nUnit, where I have one testcase containing more tests and in that way don't have to write result1.Shouldbe... AND result2.shouldbe... but only write result.shouldbe.. because the setup is the same, but the params in the testcase are different. Hope it makes sense. 
 I don't really understand the "Possibility 2" - does that mean changes outside the testproject?